# image of a dense set via a continuous surjective function is dense

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> **COR** If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and surjective, and $A\subseteq X$ is dense in X, then $f(A)$ is dense in $Y$

My definition of dense is:
D is dense in X if
$\overline{D}$=X

where the bar denotes the closure

My attempt:
We need to show that $$\overline{f(A)}=Y$$ we should prove the double inclusion.

If f is continuous
$$\overline{f(A)}\supseteq f(\overline A)=f(X)=Y$$

so now I only need to prove that
$$Y\supseteq\overline{f(A)}$$ Which is the part I am stuck at.
I know there posts about this, but none of them offers a clear definite answer.
Any idea how to finish it?

Comment: Wait a minute... it is trivial that $f(A) \subseteq Y$, hence also the closure (I assume closure in $Y$) is a subset of $Y$. You already solved the problem!

Comment: I don't know .How do I know the closure of the set does not contain elements that are not in Y?. All I know is that f(A) is in Y

Comment: What is your definition of closure?

Comment: The closure of A is  the smallest close set containing A, ie  the intersection of all close sets containing A, being the close sets the elements of a topology (X,tau) and A a subset of X

Comment: Then you see that the closure of the subset $f(A)$ cannot "exceed" the topological space (in this case $Y$).

Comment: I guess you are right! I see it now.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  codomain of a function must contain its range. Therefore, in this case, we cannot have an element $x \in X$ such that $f(x)$ does not belong to $Y$.

For example, you cannot define a function $f: \{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2\}$ by $f(x) = x$, because $f(3) = 3$ does not lie in the codomain of $f$.

For this question, you need to show that $\overline{f(A)} = Y$. You showed  that $Y \subset \overline{f(A)}$. The reverse is clear : indeed, note that $f(A) \subset  Y$ because of the first line of this answer. Now, $Y$ is a topological space, and hence is a closed subset of itself. So $Y$ is a closed set containing $f(A)$. It follows from the definition of closure that $\overline{f(A)} \subset Y$,  which completes  the argument.

Comment: Very clear. I see it now

Comment: You are welcome!